# @RequestMapping path and JQuery .get URL path

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc

Im having a problem with my JQuery $.get URL. Whenever the .js file containing my JQuery code load for the first time, the $.get URL is loaded correctly and everything works just fine, if I refreshed the JSP page linking to the .js I get PATH not mapped error. Below is my controller, jquery code:

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/load-users-data")
@ResponseBody
public UserListData listUsersData(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model) throws Exception {
  ....
  return listData;
}
```

UserDateLoader.js

```
$.get(
  '../load-users-data',
  param,
  ....
  ....
```

Note: The controller class method above is placed in a Spring MVC project

Any thoughts how I can overcome this problem?

Comment: As long as I remember, I think `..` doesn't work here.

Comment: @SazzadurRahaman Thanks, but do you have any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Why wouldn't you do a `/users/load-users-data` call directly?

Comment: @RaulRene tried it but didn't work, the problem is that the first time the script is loaded it see a path, then the second time this path is totally different for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you cannot use relative path here. If you use it, it will be relative your server root not your application's root. What you need is to provide absolute path to your JS.

And here are some ways to do that.

- you can write hard coded URL
- or write a JS function to calculate Absolute URL of the page to navigate from current location. you can find the current location in JS by `window.location.pathname`.

Comment: Can you please suggest any way?